# Python: BeautifulSoup filter all 'rel' values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, load, filtering

I need to filter all 'rel' values from HTML file, I'm using BeautifulSoup for filtering

```
    for tag in self.loadtree_parser.find_all('a'):
        print tag.get('rel')
```

gives me

```
[u'0']
[u'83']
[u'84']
[u'39']
[u'24']
[u'41']
```

I want just 'pure' numbers without weird [u'']. How can it be done?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="0" title="" id="Ta_0">
<a href="#" rel="83" title="" id="Ta_83">
<a href="#" rel="84" title="" id="Ta_84">
<a href="#" rel="39" title="" id="Ta_39">
<a href="#" rel="24" title="" id="Ta_24">
<a href="#" rel="41" title="" id="Ta_41">
```

Comment: the `u` indicates that the string is unicode instead of plain ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `print tag.get('rel')` is printing a list with one element. Elements of lists don't render quite as nicely as scalar values; try extracting the string using indexing before printing.

```
print tag.get('rel')[0]
```

Comment: what's effectively happening is the `str` method of `list` calls `repr` on the elements, which gives a more verbose printout than the usual string conversion

Answer (score 1):

In python2 the `u` next to the string literal denotes that it is unicode. If you cast it with `str(u'123')` you will get a standard string. If you want a number though, you could simply cast the value with an `int(u'123')`.

Just remember though, that what you are getting here is a single-element list, so what you would actually need to do is:

```
print int(tag.get('rel')[0])
```

***Note***: in python3 there is no `u` modifier anymore, as every string is unicode by default.